# Profile disappeared on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, accounts

I don't know what happened, but my profile disappeared and I can't access my questions nor my profile anymore. Could someone explain, and tell me how to get the answers of previous questions?

Comment: And I lost all my programming related questions and the answers, which I don't understand why?

Comment: Without any information about which profile seems to be missing, we really have no idea what happened or where to look. And again, [meta] is a distinct site; you should ask there, not here.

Comment: What happens when you logging to your profile?

Comment: I think for real problems with an account, [Contuct Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form should be used. There you may safetly descibe which account has been lost and additional info.

Comment: And you attempt to use the contact-us form, do try to provide a little bit more of information than what you provided here.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone